# jQuery click on scrollbar not registering as in the element in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is referring specifically to the jQuery dropkick plugin:

http://jamielottering.github.com/DropKick/

Scroll to the second demo where the lists overflow and there is a scrollbar. In ever browser but IE, you can interact with the scrollbar. In IE, the panel is hidden on mouse up, as if it is seeing that click as being outside of the element perhaps?

I'd love any help trying to track down the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to do it this way:

```
  $dk.bind('focus.dropkick', function (e) {
    $dk.addClass('dk_focus');
  });

  $(document.body).bind('click.dropkick', function (e) {
     $dk.removeClass('dk_open dk_focus');
  });
```

Comment: @Greg-J        Did you replace the code on line 144 in jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js with the one provided by me?

Comment: Yeah, it ended up being an issue with our live/production server. Your code worked perfectly, but I wasn't seeing the changes being pushed.

Comment: The above snippet worked perfectly for me.
Just replace `line 144` in the `dropkick.js` file with the example. No issues with our production server either. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Open custom js for dropkick and replace the following code

```
  $dk.bind('focus.dropkick', function (e) {
    $dk.addClass('dk_focus');
  }).bind('blur.dropkick', function (e) {
    $dk.removeClass('dk_open dk_focus');
  });
```

with

```
  $dk.bind('focus.dropkick', function (e) {
    $dk.addClass('dk_focus');
  });
```